# Is there a better way to compare colors?

Tags: c#, colors

So I have been on the struggle to compare colors. Nothing too insanely in depth I would just like to be able to say, is this a shade of blue, or purple, or orange etc. Not necessarily just solid colors.

Some solutions I have tried from online are casting my Color object `.ToArgb()` and checking if the value has is greater than or less than corresponding values. So something like `if (Color.ToArgb() < -13107000 && Color.ToArgb() > -15000000) // Color is blueish`

But this has proven inefficient. Unless there is some color chart I am unaware of where I can easily find these values. Have I been pointed in the totally wrong direction? Please advice how to properly compare colors (possibly unnamed) in C#.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. What is "blue"? When does blue stop being blue and move into teal?

Comment: There are 2^24 colors so not all are named, thankfully. They probably all have names if you're coding in ADA. Anyway, since your shades are going to be subjective then I'd suggest making up your own constants and applying them.

Comment: Have a predetermined set of colors that you define (or use a set that's already there, like system colors), and calculate euclidean distance between your test color and each of the set.

Comment: You know `Color` has `R`, `G` and `B` properties? Why not just check `color.B > 100` or whatever?

Comment: @Blorgbeard because you can have B higher than 100, and yet the color won't be blue ?

Comment: Sure, you'd have to add more checks, but it's more sane than checking a range with `ToArgb()`.

Comment: The proper solution is probably what @jdphenix said. You could also use a better colour-space than RGB, like Lab for example.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli "What is 'blue'" That is what I am asking. I am about to answer one second. Sorry if my question was terribly worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a quick way to visually transfer a threshold for a "shade" of blue into its integer values. Using this chart and a bit of c# code and the suggestion of @jdphenix I am able to this.

[image]

```
    private Color FromHex(string hex)
    {
        if (hex.StartsWith("#"))
            hex = hex.Substring(1);

        if (hex.Length != 6) throw new Exception("Color not valid");

        return Color.FromArgb(
            int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
            int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
            int.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    }
```

Putting the two together:

```
            // Starting blue threshold, or whatever your desired threshold is
            Color BlueLowThreshold = FromHex("#00B4FF");
            int blueLowThreshold = BlueLowThreshold.ToArgb();
            // Ending blue threshold, or whatever your desired end threshold is
            Color BlueHighThreshold = FromHex("#5000FF");
            int blueHighThreshold = BlueHighThreshold.ToArgb();
```

Thank you for your suggestions.